# Searching partial and inconsistent lengths of text within contained cell

Tags: excel

I'm sure this question has been answered, but I haven't found the answer, despite extensive searching. I'm certainly an amateur Excel user with little experience with index/array formulas.

I am receiving ranking data for offers on a website which are categorized by detailed category node id's. The report comes like this:

```
SKU
99005500@@100

SalesRank
11036541:76

11036541 = the node id (computer-security-cables)
:76 = sales ranking
```

So this means that the SKU 99005500@@100 is ranked #76 in sales in the computer-security-cables category.

I need to break down the SalesRank into the two separate values they represent, so`76` and `computer-security-cables` are listed in separate cells. In the picture it would have the category returned in the corresponding row in C column and the sales rank in D column.

If the node id's were a uniform amount of digits this wouldn't be hard to achieve, however with various lengths and various lengths of text after `:` I am unable to make it work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

http://tinyurl.com/l6j33b5
[image: SO19455851 question example]

Answer (score 0):

To extract anything up to 10 digits after the colon in `SalesRank 11036541:76` (assumed to be in A1) please try:

```
 =MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,10)
```

To find what is in parentheses in `11036541 = the node id (computer-security-cables) :76 = sales ranking` (assumed to be in A3) please try:

```
=MID(A3,FIND("(",A3)+1,FIND(")",A3)-FIND("(",A3)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Data / Text to Columns / Delimited / Other / ":" to use ":" as a seperator between the two fields